# I need to solve for $x$ in the following equation...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$3(x+1) - 7(x+1) = -4x +9$$

How do I solve for $x$?

I get $0x = 13$, which is mathematically impossible...

Comment: You are correct. $0x = 13$ is what you should have gotten. This can happen when dealing with equations that you solve for $x$. because it is mathematically impossible, there are no solutions to this equation.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: your result seems to be valid. not any equation has a solution. have you copied the assignment right?

Comment: Try graphing the left-hand-side as well as the right-hand-side, and see where the lines cross.

Answer (score 1):

> $$3(x+1) - 7(x+1) = -4x +9 $$

$$3x+3 - 7x-7 = -4x +9 $$

$$-4x = -4x +9 +7-3$$

$$0=13$$

You are correct, this is impossible **"False"**

Answer (score 1):

Your computations are indeed correct and they show that there is no solution to the equation you have to solve.

You can see that as a kind of proof by contradiction. Suppose that there exists a solution to the equation 
$$3(x+1) - 7(x+1) = -4x +9$$
then this implies that $13=0$ which is a contradiction. Thus the assumption is wrong, i.e. there is no solution to this equation.